# She hears him WALK (why not 'walking' ? )

Tags: grammaticality

I thought that the only correct form for this sentence is 'she hears him walking'.
What grammatical rule is for such usage of verb? Does it mean that such variant is correct too: I saw him walk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case both *walk* and *walking* would be fine, so:

> she can hear him walk | she can hear him walking

or

> she hears him walk | she hears him walking

are all correct, assuming that she is hearing him in present time.

"I saw him walk" is also correct as is "I saw him walking". However, more indication of the context would be needed to better explain or justify the correct usage.

Comment: Your answer is confusing, as you start out saying the sentence "she hears him walk" is "**not** grammatically correct" and then in the next sentence say it's fine.  Could you please clarify what exactly is incorrect, or perhaps just delete that bit and focus on where it would be correct.

Comment: @Andrew - This answer was written [before the title was corrected](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/185594/revisions).

Comment: Ok, What is a rule for it? What situations are ok for it?